# nginx: omit the hardcoded server ip in nginx config

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I don't want to hardcode the server ip in nginx config file. It means I should be able to run it anywhere, on any docker hosting without knowing the ip.

this is my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name 45.33.97.232;

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://45.33.97.232:3000; #port where you are serving your express app.

  }
}
```

and here is my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:3000
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./deploy/certs:/deploy/certs
      - ./deploy/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - 80:80/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
    restart: always
```

Comment: replace your IP with `_` in `server_name`.

Comment: You do not need a `server_name` directive, if there is **only one** `server` block listening with this port number. Or it's the `default_server`.

Comment: @SonuBamniya then what will be the value of `proxy_pass http://45.33.97.232:3000;`

Comment: I don't understand can't you just write localhost?

Comment: should be `proxy_pass http://$host:3000;`

Comment: @SonuBamniya but that does not replace the hardcoded ip in `server_name`, does it?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze `server_name _` will auto pick the server. He mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze  No, it doesn't, to remove the hardcoded IP from `server_name` you need to set it to `_`. Which I have mentioned in my first comment.